# Google Extension - read json object + key on hover

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a Chrome Extension that shows the object and key from a local json file in our project on hover.

So we have an app with for example a < label > or a < p > and when you hover over it, it shows a small popup with the corresponding json object and key.

**Our Vue app:**

```
<p>{{ $t('table.title') }}</p>
```

**Our local JSON (en-gb.json file):**

```
"table": {
  "title": "Templates",
  "anotherKey": "Templates",
  "anotherKey2": "Templates"
}
```

**The extension should be working like this:**

I am looking at the app and hover over the < p >, which is simply Templates. A small box shows up containing:

*table.title*

So it's basically an indicator which translation key is connected to the texts on the app.

Our project structure looks like this:

- app
- node_modules
- public
- src

  - assets
  - translations

    - en-gb.json
- package.json
- etc..

Is this possible? Making a basic extension is not the problem, the connecting the json to the extension is the part that I have some difficulty with.

And what about updates on Chrome?

Comment: It's unclear why this is a problem because reading a file is trivial and there are tons of examples. I guess you need to describe "local", "app", and "our project", "connecting the json" in more detail.

Comment: It's not a problem, I'm asking if it is possible and if yes, how does one go about making something like this?

Comment: It depends on where that json is. Without seeing more info we can only guess e.g. for a local file on the user's computer you can use `fetch` after enabling file access for the extension or use the new File System Access API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question with the file structure of our app.

Comment: If the json file is inside your extension then just use `fetch('file.json')` in the extension script e.g. in popup.js

Comment: Its a living file, so translations will be added and edited by the team, thats why I'm not really sure how to go about it..

Comment: ...and we're back to my first comment.

Comment: The json is in git, the extension is in a zip. It's not that hard to understand, right? I now get that I can use fetch with the entire url to get the file instead of it being in the extension zip. I have almost given up on this extension, as the documentation is terrible and there are no examples anywhere remotely of anything I am trying to achieve. How can something this simple be so difficult..

Comment: The extension is not in zip, it's installed in the browser, I guess. "json is in git" is vague again. You need to describe the details. Anyway, the extension can use `fetch` to read the file. For a local file it'll be a file:// URL and as I said the user would need to enable file access for the extension. There are many examples around but I can't point you to the exact one due the lack of specifics.